# How to filter all videos I watched on a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

How to filter all videos I watched on a YouTube channel? Basically, I want to **hide** all videos I haven't watched yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On YouTube's main page, there's a bunch of links on the bar to the left, the 6th link from the top is "History", which is a listing of all the videos you have watched in the past.
You can even search the history, and it goes all the way back to 2014 I think.